# is there a proper syntax for the expression or is this impossible

Tags: bash

```
STD_IN=&1

data=<( read data from $STD_IN  ; echo $data; ) 
echo $data
```

Target: Is to get a blocking read into the subshell like this

Comment: Please clarify. Perhaps give an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: it looks like a "XYProblem": please state WHAT you are trying to achieve (ie, what you NEED to do), not HOW you think you ought to achieve it (ie, how you try to do it). That way we can probably provide you with a better/easier/more portable way to do what you NEED to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Tip: one of the steps to writing a good question is writing a meaningful title. A title should uniquely identify the question, but your title is entirely void of content.

Comment: What do you want to read from stdin? A byte? a character? a fully formed character with diacritics, a line (may that line be continued with a backslash like when using `read`?), everything until end of file? all the characters sent upon a key press when stdin is a terminal? Can we make assumptions on the character set on terminal? Do you want to consume the input, or just test if there's some? Do you want the input in a shell variable? [Please update your question to give more info as it is unclear as it is. You may also want to read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

*edit* : I add corrections following Stephane Chazela's comments

I believe you want to

```
IFS= read -r data  #setting IFS to "", and reading raw (therefore can handle almost any characters)
printf "%s\n" "$data"  # printf is more portable and flexible than echo
```

?  ie, read will wait until someone enters something and press RETURN (and it puts it into data)

If you wanted to "expand" $data with something entered by a user:

```
IFS= read -r userdata
data="${data}${userdata}"  #or whichever way you want to append, maybe first userdata? maybe separated with space? etc
printf "%s\n" "$data"
```

Comment: Indeed, without details about what the actual problem is, this is the correct solution. No subshell execution is required to get standard input into the `data` variable.

Comment: `echo` doesn't support `--`. Some implementations support `-` (one dash), not `bash`'s.

Comment: Note that to read one line of data (minus the trailing newline) into `$data`, provided it doesn't contain NUL characters, the correct syntax is `IFS= read -r data`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: right and right, as always... I was lazy (didn't check the first one, and didn't bother putting the 2nd one, which is bad (doubly bad, as it's also something I don't like to see forgetted in other's posts...)). I'll correct this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
data=`cat`
```

When you call `cat` with no arguments it reads from `stdin`.  The caveat us you'll have to terminate input with an EOF.